# WordPress WooCommerce как сделать выбор оформить как гость или зарегестрироваться?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

WordPress - Woocommerce, как сделать такой выбор?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Woocommerce -> Настройки -> Учетки и приватность

Comment: По другому будет. Выбор появится на странице "оформления заказа", а мне нужно до неё.

Comment: Что насчет woocommerce_login_form()?